# ld: framework not found -Accelerate clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode5, apptentive

i am trying to implement Apptentive SDK in my iPhone application as per the guide document.
everything was gone good. but at last point of implementing SDK found error.that is Accelerate framework directory path not fount like that a error occurs

**ld: framework not found -Accelerate
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: Which versions of Xcode and the iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: i'm using xcode Version 5.0

Comment: can you give solution for this issues?

Answer (score 0):

it may be Xcode version in-compatability issues, if we change directory path it may works